# Spring RestTemplate - Specifying Jackson View

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a rest client class which is responsible for making calls to a rest service using a single Spring RestTemplate bean to do the HTTP exchanges. This includes serialization of MyObject.java via MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java.

When creating (POST) a MyObject I send 5 fields.

When updating (PUT) a MyObject I must only send 3 (the mutable fields).

I want a single DTO, MyObject, that serializes differently under different circumstances: POST vs PUT. Step in Jackson Views which solve this problems perfectly.

My problem is that ObjectMapper is hidden away in the RestTemplate messageConverters which makes it hard to add context at REST exchange time as to which View I want the ObjectMapper to use when serializing.

Is there any way to achieve this or do I need 2 distinct RestTemplates, one configured with an Object mapper for creation and one for updating. This seems like a lot of duplication.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: I'll see if I can add some tonight

Answer (score 1):

You can configure ObjectMapper or the DTO itself to ignore nulls during serialization. Then only set the fields you want to pass in your DTO.

Comment: I don't really want to do that. MyObject has an ID which immutable and belongs with that object, it just so happens that in the context of serialization for update, I don't want to send it. 

At the moment I am creating an updateDto which does not have those fields, it just seems a bit messy.